# New error for unchanged Google Script that loops google sheet rows, copies rows to doc templates, merge templates into a one file and delete rest

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Script worked without any errors for the past 4 years until now (Not the same sheet but created a new blank sheet every month and copied the doc template and google script). No adjustments to script, sheet and doc template prior to the error. The issue started on Oct 17 2023 15:13 CEST.

The error message is as follows: **Service Documents failed while accessing document with id** followed with a long id.

The google script is as follows:

```
function createMergedVouchers()
{  
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Vouchers');
  var activeSelection = activeSheet.getSheetValues(2, 1, activeSheet.getLastRow()-1,activeSheet.getMaxColumns());
  var headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 13).getValues();
  
  var copyFile;
  var copyId;
  var copyDoc;
  var copyBody; 
  
  var base;
  var bodySelection;
  var totalElements;
  var element;
  var type;
    
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < activeSelection.length; rowIndex++)
  {
    copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(VOUCHER_ID).makeCopy(); // copies voucher template
    copyId = copyFile.getId(); // reads ID of copied file
    copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId); // opens copied file
    copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection(); // reads copied file    
    
    copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][1] + '%', activeSelection[rowIndex][1]); 
    copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][2] + '%', activeSelection[rowIndex][2]);
    // shortened code snipped
    copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][12] + '%', activeSelection[rowIndex][12]); 

    if (rowIndex == 0)
    {
      copyDoc.setName('Merged Vouchers');        
      base = DocumentApp.openById(copyId).getBody();
    }
    else
    {
      bodySelection = DocumentApp.openById(copyId).getBody();
      totalElements = copyBody.getNumChildren();      
      for (var elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < totalElements; elementIndex++)
      {
        element = copyBody.getChild(elementIndex).copy();
        type = element.getType();        
        if(type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH)
        {          
          base.appendParagraph(element);
        }
        else if(type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE)
        {          
          base.appendTable(element);
        }
        else if(type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM)
        {          
          base.appendListItem(element);
        }
        else
        {
          throw new Error("Unknown element type: "+type);
        }        
      }
      DriveApp.getFolderById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Using the script with a 5 row sheet works however when tested with 6 or more the script gives the error which never happened before. Its not a matter of increased volume as the script handled up to 100-150 rowed sheets with no issues in the past.

Was not expecting an error with no code change that worked without any issue for 4 years.

Comment: Is the VOUCHER_ID defined?

Comment: Yes the  VOUCHER_ID is defined and was unchanged.

Comment: I did not include it in the code snippet.

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: When the script runs in sheets, a tooltip appears stating the script is running. Usually after its done, the tooltip says succesful but instead is it says "Service Documents failed while accessing document with id"

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: When the script runs in sheets, a tooltip appears stating the script is running. Usually after its done, the tooltip says succesful but instead is it says "Service Documents failed while accessing document with id"

Comment: Look in executions to see if you can determine what line is causing the error.

Comment: getActiveSection is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work because I don't really know what getActiveSection() did for sure.  But you can give it try if you dare.

```
function createMergedVouchers() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Vouchers');
  var activeSelection = sh.getSheetValues(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getMaxColumns());
  var headerRow = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, 13).getValues();
  var copyFile;
  var copyId;
  var copyDoc;
  var copyBody;
  var base;
  var totalElements;
  var element;
  var type;
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < activeSelection.length; rowIndex++) {
    copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(VOUCHER_ID).makeCopy();
    copyId = copyFile.getId();
    copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
    copyBody = copyDoc.getBody();
    copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][1] + '%', activeSelection[rowIndex][1]);
    copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][2] + '%', activeSelection[rowIndex][2]);
    copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][12] + '%', activeSelection[rowIndex][12]);
    if (rowIndex == 0) {
      copyDoc.setName('Merged Vouchers');
      base = copyDoc.getBody();
    } else {
      totalElements = copyBody.getNumChildren();
      for (var elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < totalElements; elementIndex++) {
        element = copyBody.getChild(elementIndex).copy();
        type = element.getType();
        if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
          base.appendParagraph(element);
        } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
          base.appendTable(element);
        } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
          base.appendListItem(element);
        } else {
          throw new Error("Unknown element type: " + type);
        }
      }
      DriveApp.getFolderById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried it but I still got the same error - Service Documents failed while accessing document with id

Comment: What line is it occuring on?

Comment: I ran the script again (a day later) and have no error now. Currently running the script again.

Comment: No errors after running thr script two more times each time with a larger sheet.